# Can anyone please suggest a decent online community to keep track of daily fitness?

Tags: tracking

I've read many times, keeping track or keeping daily journal entries helps you stay motivated. However, I always find it hard to keep journaling hard alone. Can anyone knows a platform where I can keep my fitness journal.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fitocracy](https://www.fitocracy.com/home/). It lets you log the workouts you do to keep track of your progress, and also publishes your workouts to a feed that your followers will see. So you can "journal" by adding a note to your workout, like

> Pull-up
>     7 reps
>     7 reps
>     7 reps
>     "I think the flexed arm hang is increasing my range of motion on these. The first one especially I popped up way over the bar."

There are also numerous groups so if you have something particular to say about triathlons, you can pop in and talk to people who understand.

Comment: The community there is also super friendly and supportive.